# Magento 1.9 fetch specific cateogry on top level menu in header

Tags: magento-1.9, category, menu, header

I have added custom attribute for Categories section .I want to fetch specific categories only based on custom attribute value in header .
I want to modify this code :

```
$this->getChildHtml('topMenu') 

$_menu = $this->getHtml('level-top')
```

I found this method getHtml() , but I am not understanding where  to alter query to get specific categories.

Comment: you need to modify the block file of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR**

you need to override method `_getDefaultCollection` in `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category_Tree` :

```
protected function _getDefaultCollection($sorted = false)
{
    $this->_joinUrlRewriteIntoCollection = true;
    $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection();
    /** @var $collection Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category_Collection */
    // your filters here
    $collection = $collection->addAttributeToFilter('attribute_code', 'attribute_value');

 ...
 }
```

**More detailed description:**

The category tree rendering on frontend starts in `app/code/core/Mage/Page/Block/Html/Topmenu.php`

when event `page_block_html_topmenu_gethtml_before` is fired:

```
public function getHtml($outermostClass = '', $childrenWrapClass = '')
{
    Mage::dispatchEvent('page_block_html_topmenu_gethtml_before', array(
        'menu' => $this->_menu,
        'block' => $this
    ));
...
```

This event is listened by observer in `Mage_Catalog_Block_Category::addCatalogToTopmenuItems` which calls method `getStoreCategories` of `catalog/category` helper:

```
public function addCatalogToTopmenuItems(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    ...
    $this->_addCategoriesToMenu(
        Mage::helper('catalog/category')->getStoreCategories(), $observer->getMenu(), $block
    );
}
```

Which eventually leads to :

```
public function getStoreCategories($sorted=false, $asCollection=false, $toLoad=true)
{
    ...
    $storeCategories = $category->getCategories($parent, $recursionLevel, $sorted, $asCollection, $toLoad);
    ...
}
```

Where `getCategories` method is lead to `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category_Tree` resource model method.

Comment: Can you please tell me what is the use of page_block_html_topmenu_gethtml_before & page_block_html_topmenu_gethtml_after dispatch event ? & how did u understand that observer is Mage_Catalog_Block_Category::addCatalogToTopmenuItems?

Comment: `page_block_html_topmenu_gethtml_before ` is used in core to add category elements into a tree and `page_block_html_topmenu_gethtml_after` for custom purposes, and as far as I know not used in system. considering observer and `addCatalogToTopmenuItems` method, i looked into a code and when i did not found collection calls in it, i searched config.xml in modules for string `page_block_html_topmenu_gethtml_before` (I used in phpstorm `find in path` )

Comment: & how did you find getCategories belong to Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category_Tree?

Comment: take a look into `Mage_Catalog_Model_Category::getCategories` it is calling  `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category::getCategories` which is calling `Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/category_tree')->addCollectionData()` which is calling `$this->addCollectionData()` and from then skipping couple others methods it is calling `_getDefaultCollection` method

Comment: Thank you so much!you explained really well.Can  I ask you one more question?

Comment: thanks, sure  but if this another topic better create a new thread cause i cant guarantee when ill be online on SO